# Blank row inserted in database instead of passed value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I'm trying to insert value using c to `sqlite3` but instead of the passed value a blank row inserted in a table

```
int main() {
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc ;
rc = sqlite3_open("mydb.db", &db);

if (rc)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
}

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select * FROM `99940` a INNER JOIN (SELECT rowid FROM `Search_99940` ('B Rujesh P Balakrishnan')) b ON b.rowid = a.rowid WHERE upper(a.circle) = ('TAMIL NADU')", -1, &stmt, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, 16);

if ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    string try1 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)));
    string try2 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)));
    string try3 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)));
    string try4 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)));
    string try5 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5)));
    string try6 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6)));
    string try7 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 7)));
    string try8 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 8)));
    string try9 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 9)));


    char* errorMessage;
    sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);

    char buffer[] = "INSERT INTO `99946` (Number,Full_Name,Address,Date,Circle,Operator,Alterno,IDProof,SimType)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";   
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, NULL);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, try1.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, try2.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, try3.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, try4.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, try5.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, try6.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, try7.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, try8.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 9, try9.c_str(), 0, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            printf("Commit Failed!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Success!\n");
        }
        sqlite3_reset(stmt);
   }
    sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL,NULL, &errorMessage);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

return 0;
```

}

My selection query works fine and also I get value in `try1` to `try9`. Like `try1 = 'xyz'` and I get that value using

```
string try1 = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)));
```

What is wrong I don't understand please help me to resolve this issue.  Is the way I am trying to insert is wrong I don't understand

Comment: I suggest to check the return code of all functions. Maybe you would get an error indication where something is wrong with a `sqlite3*_()` call.

Comment: This is no C code but C++. Please use correct language tags for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `0` bytes as of now.

**Explanation:**

```
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, try1.c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

And syntax is

```
int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*,int,const char*,int,void(*)(void*));
```

As per [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_bind_blob)

> The third argument is the value to bind to the parameter. If the third
>   parameter to sqlite3_bind_text() or sqlite3_bind_text16() or
>   sqlite3_bind_blob() is a NULL pointer then the fourth parameter is
>   ignored and the end result is the same as sqlite3_bind_null().
>
> In those routines that have a fourth argument, its value is the number
>   of bytes in the parameter. To be clear: the value is the number of
>   bytes in the value, not the number of characters. If the fourth
>   parameter to sqlite3_bind_text() or sqlite3_bind_text16() is negative,
>   then the length of the string is the number of bytes up to the first
>   zero terminator.

---

Thus change it to as below to write until null byte.

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, try1.c_str(), -1, NULL);
```